# I am not able to install python purl package?

Tags: python, url

I am using `Ubuntu` and not able to install `purl` packages. I use `pip` and the `github` unstable version to install, but none works and it says permission denied.

How do I install purl package from `Pypi`. I need help.
Also, how are the different ways of installing packages like these other than `apt-get` and `pip`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For installing system-wide packages, you need root rights, so try `sudo pip install purl`. You could also use virtualenv so you don't need to be root:

```
$ virtualenv venv
$ . venv/bin/activate
(venv)$ pip install purl
```

Answer (score -1):

There's no `purl` on Ubuntu official repository, so you can install it by pip, using `sudo` command:

```
sudo pip install purl
```